# Select without negative values in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select needed values without negative `Total` values according to this query?

[image]

Second row should not be returned as the `Total` value is less than 0.

```
SELECT DealerCode, PaymentType, Total  
FROM DEL_Purchases 
WHERE DealerCode = 'A0686P'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you just need 2 columns: DealerCode, PaymentType?

Comment: give us all your columns

Comment: acording to the image link http://i.stack.imgur.com/67b6v.jpg you can see, there is two rows from same Dealer Code, but one of Total is - minus.. so i need to execute and take the result without minus total.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to *only* SELECT non-negative numbers (0,1,2..) and not SELECT negative numbers (-1,-2,-3..). Correct?

Comment: Yes that's what wanted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DealerCode, PaymentType, Total from DEL_Purchases 
where DealerCode='A0686P' and Total > 0
```